# Custom Radio Group

Tags: android

I am trying to make a group activity with the radio widget. My problem is that i cant seem to delete the speaker icon that come with the radio button any help would be great thanks.

http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/3131/helpnj.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp" android:background="@drawable/tilte2">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@null"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to customize the radio button look..

Create a selector xml (radio_btn_selector.xml) in the drawable folder as.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_image" 
    android:state_pressed="true"/>  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checked_image" 
    android:state_checked="true"/>  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/focused_image" 
    android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_image" />  
</selector>
```

Now use the selector as button type in the Radio Button.

```
<RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@null"
```

`android:button="@drawable/radio_btn_selector"`/>

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a ToggleButton instead?
A RadioButton without the icon is like a ToggleButton :)